# Are these both considered Builder pattern? They're extremely different and have totally different implementations and purposes

Tags: design-patterns

I've taken two Design Pattern courses now. 1 had this pattern below (note the lack of an interface).

```
class Coffee{

    private String name;
    private int acidity;
    private int sweetness;
    private String roastType;
    private int aromatic;
    private String quality;
    private int priceInDollarsPer100g;



    public Coffee(Builder builder) {
        this.name = builder.name;
        this.acidity = builder.acidity;
        this.sweetness = builder.sweetness;
        this.roastType = builder.roastType;
        this.aromatic = builder.aromatic;
        this.quality = builder.quality;
        this.priceInDollarsPer100g = builder.priceInDollarsPer100g;
    }

    public static class Builder{

        private Builder builder;

        private String name;
        private int acidity;
        private int sweetness;
        private String roastType;
        private int aromatic;
        private String quality;
        private int priceInDollarsPer100g;


        // Only 1 field is mandatory
        public Builder(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Builder setAcidity(int acidity){
            this.acidity = acidity;

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setSweetness(int sweetness) {
            this.sweetness = sweetness;

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setRoastType(String roastType) {
            this.roastType = roastType;

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAromatic(int aromatic) {
            this.aromatic = aromatic;

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setQuality(String quality) {
            this.quality = quality;

            return this;
        }

        public Builder setPriceInDollarsPer100g(int priceInDollarsPer100g) {
            this.priceInDollarsPer100g = priceInDollarsPer100g;

            return this;
        }

        public Coffee build(){

            return new Coffee(this);
        }
    }
}
```

But in the next course there is no mention of this pattern at all. If I adapt it to the "interface/prescriptive/Static-product way", I get this:

```
package Builder.BuilderPattern2;


interface CoffeeAttributes {

    void setName(String name);
    void setAcidity(int acidity);
    void setSweetness(int sweetness);
    void setRoastType(String roastType);
    void setAromatic(int aromatic);
    void setQuality(String quality);
    void setPriceInDollarsPer100g(int priceInDollarsPer100g);
}

class Coffee implements CoffeeAttributes {

    private String name;
    private int acidity;
    private int sweetness;
    private String roastType;
    private int aromatic;
    private String quality;
    private int priceInDollarsPer100g;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAcidity(int acidity) {
        this.acidity = acidity;
    }

    public void setSweetness(int sweetness) {
        this.sweetness = sweetness;
    }

    public void setRoastType(String roastType) {
        this.roastType = roastType;
    }

    public void setAromatic(int aromatic) {
        this.aromatic = aromatic;
    }

    public void setQuality(String quality) {
        this.quality = quality;
    }

    public void setPriceInDollarsPer100g(int priceInDollarsPer100g) {
        this.priceInDollarsPer100g = priceInDollarsPer100g;
    }
}


interface CoffeeBuilder{

    public void buildName();
    public void buildAcidity();
    public void buildSweetness();
    public void buildRoastType();
    public void buildAromatic();
    public void buildQuality();
    public void buildPriceInDollarsPer100g();

    public Coffee getCoffee();
}


class ZestyFrenchRoast implements CoffeeBuilder{

    private Coffee coffee;


    public ZestyFrenchRoast(){
        this.coffee = new Coffee();
    }


    public void buildName() {
        this.coffee.setName("Zesty French Flave");
    }


    public void buildAcidity() {
        this.coffee.setAcidity(3);
    }


    public void buildSweetness() {
        this.coffee.setSweetness(10);
    }


    public void buildRoastType() {
        this.coffee.setRoastType("French");
    }


    public void buildAromatic() {
        this.coffee.setAromatic(7);
    }


    public void buildQuality() {
        this.coffee.setQuality("Medium");
    }


    public void buildPriceInDollarsPer100g() {
        this.coffee.setPriceInDollarsPer100g(3);
    }


    public Coffee getCoffee() {
        return this.coffee;
    }
}


class CoffeeMaker{

    private CoffeeBuilder coffeeBuilder;

    public CoffeeMaker(CoffeeBuilder coffeeBuilder){

        this.coffeeBuilder = coffeeBuilder;
    }

    public Coffee getCoffee(){
        return this.coffeeBuilder.getCoffee();
    }

    public void makeCoffee(){

        this.coffeeBuilder.buildName();
        this.coffeeBuilder.buildAcidity();
        this.coffeeBuilder.buildAromatic();
        this.coffeeBuilder.buildPriceInDollarsPer100g();
        this.coffeeBuilder.buildQuality();
        this.coffeeBuilder.buildRoastType();
        this.coffeeBuilder.buildSweetness();
    }
}



public class BuilderPattern2{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CoffeeBuilder coffeeToBuild = new ZestyFrenchRoast();

        CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker = new CoffeeMaker(coffeeToBuild);

        coffeeMaker.makeCoffee();

        Coffee coffee = coffeeMaker.getCoffee();

        System.out.println("The barista hands you a delicious cup of some kind of " +
                "coffee but because there are no getters in this pattern we have no idea " +
                "what it is. " + "Please pick it up at " + coffee);
    }
}
```

RE: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builder-design-pattern/

There are no getters in the second version so obviously you wouldn't put text in the object, it would be a more abstract thing. I'm just at a loss to see these two patterns having the same name!

Comment: It depends what you are building I guess. Also the second half of your question seems missing

Comment: @MatthewEvans Yeah I'm sorry about that. I'm working on that now, accidentally clicked Ask. 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example shows the essential Builder Pattern. It can be used to avoid creating multiple constructors. If you sometimes need to add Name and Student ID, or other times you need to add Name, Address and Phone number, a single object Builder is very useful for that.

The second example is a **Factory Builder**!
It can be used to define priveleges for different kinds of users. These priveleges don't often change but vary among the types of users you have. That's where factory comes in.
Basically it's used to create a PRODUCT and that product does not often change.